# Why can't I run more than two threads at once?

Tags: python, multithreading, turtle-graphics

I am new to threading so please excuse me if I am missing something completely obvious.

This is my code (a turtle race):

(Skip to the bottom of the code for the threading part)

```
import turtle
from random import randint
import threading


n = turtle.Turtle()
n.speed(10)
n.hideturtle()
n.penup()
n.goto(-600, 300)
n.pendown()

for x in range(1, 51):
    n.forward(12)
    n.write(x)
    n.forward(12)

n.right(90)
n.forward(270)
n.right(90)
n.forward(1200)
n.right(90)
n.forward(270)
n.right(180)
n.forward(15)
n.left(90)

for x in range(0, 4):
    n.forward(1200)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(30)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(1200)
    n.left(90)
    n.forward(30)
    n.left(90)

n.forward(1200)
n.right(90)

red = turtle.Turtle()
blue = turtle.Turtle()
green = turtle.Turtle()
orange = turtle.Turtle()
brown = turtle.Turtle()
black = turtle.Turtle()
pink = turtle.Turtle()
purple = turtle.Turtle()

turtles = {
    red: ['red', 270],
    blue: ['blue', 240],
    green: ['green', 210],
    orange: ['orange', 180],
    brown: ['brown', 150],
    black: ['black', 120],
    pink: ['pink', 90],
    purple: ['purple', 60]
}

for x in turtles:
    x.color(turtles[x][0])
    x.shape('turtle')
    x.penup()
    x.goto(-600, turtles[x][1])


def move_red(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        red.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        red.forward(5)
    return

def move_blue(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        blue.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        blue.forward(5)
    return

def move_green(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        green.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        green.forward(5)
    return

def move_orange(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        orange.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        orange.forward(5)
    return

def move_brown(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        brown.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        brown.forward(5)
    return

def move_black(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        black.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        black.forward(5)
    return

def move_pink(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        pink.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        pink.forward(5)
    return

def move_purple(num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        purple.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        purple.forward(5)
    return

t1 = threading.Thread(target = move_red, args = [1, 10])
t2 = threading.Thread(target = move_blue, args = [1, 10])
t3 = threading.Thread(target = move_green, args = [1, 10])
t4 = threading.Thread(target = move_orange, args = [1, 10])
t5 = threading.Thread(target = move_brown, args = [1, 10])
t6 = threading.Thread(target = move_black, args = [1, 10])
t7 = threading.Thread(target = move_pink, args = [1, 10])
t8 = threading.Thread(target = move_purple, args = [1, 10])

ts = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8]
for x in ts:
    x.start()

turtle.done()
```

If you run this in your editor, you will see the turtles stopping at random times. This doesn't happen when I run 2 threads. `.join()` doesn't help either. Please explain to me why the threads aren't working.

Comment: Is that first `n` turtle important to this question or could that part be removed?

Comment: That's a fun program. They all ran for me, but some lagged way behind. Python only lets 1 thread run at a time (google the GIL) and for some reason some threads are being starved for time. I added `time.sleep(.1)` to each of the functions and they all ran together.

Comment: The problem is probably because the graphics the `turtle` module does are based on the `tkinter` module which doesn't support threading—at least not the direct way you're doing it.

Comment: About the .join .... you should only call tkinter on the main thread. If you don't join the threads it has the side effect that `turtle.done()` is called before the threads start. I can't explain why this seems to make tkinter happy with calling from other threads, but if you join, you get an error about calling tkinter in the wrong thread. The upshot is that although you could do calculations in the background, its not safe to call turtle itself from other threads.

Comment: And why did this get a downvote?! Its a good question.

Comment: @martineau - what still puzzles me is that calls to tkinter from other threads worked.

Comment: FWIW, the `turtle` module does animation (e.g. the turtle moving and turning) by using the `tkinter` universal `after` method, which delays the given amount of time before calling the specified function (which all happens within `tkinter`'s `mainloop()`). This is a good example of why it's incompatible with naive (direct) attempts at multi-threading. I suspect that getting this to function properly in such an environment would require a great deal of investigation into how it's implemented in order to get it to figure out if there's a way to do it properly—more than I'm willing to do, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but you need to limit your turtle operations that invoke tkinter to the main thread. Below is my tear down and rebuild of your program to work this way and remove redundancies.  (I left off the background drawing which you can add back.) I used a thread safe queue data structure to communicate between the threads and tkinter:

```
from threading import Thread, active_count
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint
from queue import Queue  # use for thread-safe communications

QUEUE_SIZE = 1  # set higher the more unused hardware threads you have
COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'brown', 'black', 'pink', 'purple']

def move_turtle(turtle):
    for _ in range(240):
        actions.put((turtle.forward, randint(1, 10)))

def process_queue():
    while not actions.empty():
        action, argument = actions.get()
        action(argument)

    if active_count() > 1:
        screen.ontimer(process_queue, 100)

actions = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 600)

threads = []

for y, color in enumerate(COLORS):
    turtle = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-600, 270 - y * 30)
    turtle.showturtle()

    thread = Thread(target=move_turtle, args=[turtle])
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

process_queue()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

> I don't want the turtles to move forward random distances; I want them
>   to move forward the same distance, just at different speeds

You can do that with the environment I setup:

```
def move_turtle(turtle):
    for _ in range(240):
        actions.put((turtle.speed, randint(1, 10)))
        actions.put((turtle.forward, 5))
```

But `turtle.speed()` is about *drawing speed* and you're only (not) drawing a five pixel line so the speed of drawing makes little difference.  By the middle of the race, this is what is happening:

[image]

Even setting the turtles to random speeds *before* the race, and not changing them, makes no difference.  I think varying the forward distance makes for a more exciting race.

Comment: I don't want the turtles to move forward random distances; I want them to move forward the same distance, just at different speeds

Comment: @flameboi, this is something you could have tried with the code I provided, you don't need me to do it for you.  However, I've augmented my answer with code and illustration of using different speeds and why I chose not to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a library named `threaded_turtle` which uses the same approach as what @cdlane offered in his answer, but does the "smart" work behind the scenes.

You gen find the library on gitlab: https://gitlab.com/zvone/threaded_turtle

Here is the same code as in the question, modified to work with `threaded_turtle` library:

```
import turtle
from random import randint

from threaded_turtle import ThreadSerializer, TurtleThread


n = turtle.Turtle()
n.speed(10)
n.hideturtle()
n.penup()
n.goto(-600, 300)
n.pendown()

for x in range(1, 51):
    n.forward(12)
    n.write(x)
    n.forward(12)

n.right(90)
n.forward(270)
n.right(90)
n.forward(1200)
n.right(90)
n.forward(270)
n.right(180)
n.forward(15)
n.left(90)

for x in range(0, 4):
    n.forward(1200)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(30)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(1200)
    n.left(90)
    n.forward(30)
    n.left(90)

n.forward(1200)
n.right(90)

red = turtle.Turtle()
blue = turtle.Turtle()
green = turtle.Turtle()
orange = turtle.Turtle()
brown = turtle.Turtle()
black = turtle.Turtle()
pink = turtle.Turtle()
purple = turtle.Turtle()

turtles = {
    red: ['red', 270],
    blue: ['blue', 240],
    green: ['green', 210],
    orange: ['orange', 180],
    brown: ['brown', 150],
    black: ['black', 120],
    pink: ['pink', 90],
    purple: ['purple', 60]
}

for x in turtles:
    x.color(turtles[x][0])
    x.shape('turtle')
    x.penup()
    x.goto(-600, turtles[x][1])


def move_red(red, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        red.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        red.forward(5)
    return

def move_blue(blue, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        blue.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        blue.forward(5)
    return

def move_green(green, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        green.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        green.forward(5)
    return

def move_orange(orange, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        orange.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        orange.forward(5)
    return

def move_brown(brown, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        brown.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        brown.forward(5)
    return

def move_black(black, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        black.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        black.forward(5)
    return

def move_pink(pink, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        pink.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        pink.forward(5)
    return

def move_purple(purple, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        purple.speed(randint(num1, num2))
        purple.forward(5)
    return

ctrl = ThreadSerializer()
t1 = TurtleThread(ctrl, red, target=move_red, args=[1, 10])
t2 = TurtleThread(ctrl, blue, target=move_blue, args=[1, 10])
t3 = TurtleThread(ctrl, green, target=move_green, args=[1, 10])
t4 = TurtleThread(ctrl, orange, target=move_orange, args=[1, 10])
t5 = TurtleThread(ctrl, brown, target=move_brown, args=[1, 10])
t6 = TurtleThread(ctrl, black, target=move_black, args=[1, 10])
t7 = TurtleThread(ctrl, pink, target=move_pink, args=[1, 10])
t8 = TurtleThread(ctrl, purple, target=move_purple, args=[1, 10])

ts = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8]
for x in ts:
    x.start()

ctrl.run_forever()
```

The code could be made simpler, though. I would do something like this:

```
import turtle
import time
from random import randint
from threaded_turtle import ThreadSerializer, TurtleThread

def draw_background():
    n = turtle.Turtle()
    n.speed(10)
    n.hideturtle()
    n.penup()
    n.goto(-600, 300)
    n.pendown()

    for x in range(1, 51):
        n.forward(12)
        n.write(x)
        n.forward(12)

    n.right(90)
    n.forward(270)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(1200)
    n.right(90)
    n.forward(270)
    n.right(180)
    n.forward(15)
    n.left(90)

    for x in range(0, 4):
        n.forward(1200)
        n.right(90)
        n.forward(30)
        n.right(90)
        n.forward(1200)
        n.left(90)
        n.forward(30)
        n.left(90)

    n.forward(1200)
    n.right(90)


def move_turtle(t, num1, num2):
    for y in range(0, 240):
        time.sleep(randint(num1, num2) * 0.02)
        t.forward(randint(1, 10))
    return

draw_background()
ctrl = ThreadSerializer()

colors = 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'brown', 'black', 'pink', 'purple'
threads = []
for i, color in enumerate(colors):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.color(color)
    t.shape('turtle')
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-600, 270 - 30 * i)
    threads.append(TurtleThread(ctrl, t, target=move_turtle, args=[1, 10]))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

ctrl.run_forever()
```

Note also that I am using `time.sleep(randint(num1, num2) * 0.02)`, rather than `t.speed(randint(num1, num2))`, because that is the right way to slow down the turtle if you don't want to change the distance it moves.

Result:

[image: screenshot of turtle race taken seconds after start]